# Getting Log4j-bom-2.12.1 in spring-boot after upgrading to 2.17.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j

In prod, our project uses Spring Boot 2.2.6.RELEASE version.
To migrate from Log4j-2.12.1, I followed the official spring suggestion and have added this in pom.xml
`<log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>`
and also tried adding log4j-bom version in dependency management

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        ... other dependencies including spring-boot-dependencies
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

When a build for the project is created the jar contains only log4j-2.17.1 version jars but during build its downloading log4j-bom-2.12.1 version.

Our infra team has restricted downloading of version 2.12.1 and thus builds are failing.

Is there any way to prevent downloading of log4j-bom version 2.12.1 ?

**Stripped Down minimal version of spring to replicate the issue**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>logTester</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>logTester</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.17.1</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[image]

Comment: Switch the order. Make the log4j one the last one. if you are using spring boot as a parent the version trick should work (and is the preferred way) if that doesn't work something else is pulling in that dependency. Show your dependencies in your question.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have added minimal version of the pom.xml which can be use to replicate the issue.

Comment: The problem is that it will download all transitive dependencies, regardless of it being used (as it needs to determine dependencies). You could try adding a dependency management on `spring-boot-dependencies` and add an exclusion for the log4j2 stuff. However I would expect the version to work.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** use `-Dlog4j2.version=2.19.0` on the command line.

Before starting the build process Maven computes the effective POM of your project and **all its ancestors**.

When building the effective model of your POM everything goes smoothly: your POM inherits `log4j-bom` from its parent, but the placeholder `${log4j2.version}` is replaced with the value you gave in your POM (`2.17.1`).

However, when Maven builds the effective POM of `spring-boot-dependencies`, it replaces `${log4j2.version}` with the original value `2.12.1` specified in that POM. This does not have any influence on the dependencies of your project, but causes a download attempt of `log4j-bom-2.12.1.pom`.

To prevent that from happening you must ensure that `${log4j2.version}` is **always** replaced with `2.17.1`. You can do this by adding:

```
-Dlog4j2.version=2.17.1
```

to your command line (cf. [model interpolation](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.6/maven-model-builder/#model-interpolation)).

**Remark**: your infra team has no reason to block the download of `pom` dependencies, since they contain no code. They also do not need to blacklist all Log4j2 artifacts: only older versions of `log4j-core` have security vulnerabilities, the other artifacts are fine.